# "Forbidden" error while remotely accessing elmah.axd through HTTPS in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-2.0, iis-6, elmah

I'm trying to integrate ELMAH in a webforms application. For reasons that I am not allowed to change, the whole application must be accessed only through HTTPS.

The application is working, but we cannot access ELMAH's log file remotely. I have followed [this](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages) instructions in order to allow remote access with no success.

This is the related configuration currently in the production web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
            <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" requirePermission="false" />
        <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
    </elmah>

    <system.web>

        <httpModules>
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
        </httpModules>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>
```

Is there anything else I could do? Anyone knows if there is some kind of restriction in accessing ELMAH's log file through HTTPS?

Notice that we are currently using IIS 6.0 and .NET framework 2.0.

Comment: Your web.config is configured with security allowRemoteAccess="yes" whereas the referenced documentation you linked to indicates security allowRemoteAccess="1"

Comment: @tawman: From Elmah's documentation: To enable remote access, the value of the allowRemoteAccess attribute can be 1, yes, true or on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place a simple html file in the same directory.
2. Try to access that file.

If you can't access that file, it's a directory permissions problem. Because there's no physical axd file, there are no permissions for it per se, so I would tend to think directory security.

I don't think this has anything to do with SSL - a 403 means "you're not allowed to access this item"...that shouldn't have anything to do with the transport security. That is, unless it worked fine, until you turned on SSL.

You might also check execute rights on the directory...allow everything (read, write, execute) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: In fact I *was* able to access any other file in the same directory. But after I allowed everything it started working - and kept working after I turn those rights to what they were before! Seems to be another IIS6 "feature"... But I'll give you the accepted flag anyway :)

Answer (score 10):

Solution: 
in your config file: 
Change the 0 to 1

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
```

to

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
```

which works like a charm.

Enjoy!!

Comment: I have never used `<security allowRemoteAccess="0" />`. My configuration file had this line: `<security allowRemoteAccess="yes" requirePermission="false" />`. Both `yes` and `1` are accepted.